# pulseaudio: 0 sink input(s) available

Tags: audio

I am trying to record other apps audio using `pulseaudio`. Following this answer https://askubuntu.com/questions/60837/record-a-programs-output-with-pulseaudio/60856#60856, I am unable to reproduce it on macos.

I started with this command `pacmd list-sink-inputs` it returns:

```
0 sink input(s) available.
```

And this is the output of `pacmd list-sinks`:

```
1 sink(s) available.
  * index: 0
    name: <Channel_1__Channel_2.2>
    driver: <module-coreaudio-device.c>
    flags: HARDWARE DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY 
    state: SUSPENDED
    suspend cause: IDLE
    priority: 9000
    volume: front-left: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB,   front-right: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB
            balance 0.00
    base volume: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB
    volume steps: 65537
    muted: no
    current latency: 0.00 ms
    max request: 0 KiB
    max rewind: 0 KiB
    monitor source: 1
    sample spec: float32le 2ch 44100Hz
    channel map: front-left,front-right
                 Stereo
    used by: 0
    linked by: 0
    fixed latency: 250.00 ms
    card: 1 <Built-in_Output>
    module: 7
    properties:
        device.string = "Built-in Output"
        device.product.name = "Built-in Output"
        device.description = "Built-in Output"
        device.access_mode = "mmap"
        device.class = "sound"
        device.api = "CoreAudio"
        device.buffering.buffer_size = "4096"
        device.vendor.name = "Apple Inc."
        device.icon_name = "audio-card"
```

Any idea?

Comment: You'll probably find Mac users are far more likely to be using BlackHole, perhaps still SoundFlower which was the giant's shoulder the rest stand on, or something commercial from Rogue Amoeba.

Comment: I am using those but I am asking to do it with pa ;)

Comment: Sorry, never used it, I've no idea.There's no 'official' Mac build afaik.

Comment: Ok thanks! I installed it via homebrew tho